# Python 3 - Code will not recognize a user input larger than 1 as numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created the following python code for an exercise in Python for informatics. The code will run, but will not recognize an input form the user that is larger than 1 as numeric. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        if float(string) == True:
            return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

user_input = input('Please enter a real number. Type \"done\" to exit and tally your entries \n> ')
data = 0
count = 0

while isfloat(user_input) == True:
    data = data + float(user_input)
    count = count + 1
    user_input = input("Please enter another value \n> ")
    isfloat(user_input)

else:
    if (isfloat(user_input) == False) and (user_input == "done"):
        print("The sum of your entries is: " + str(data))
        print("The number of entries was: " + str(count))
        exit()
    else:
        print("The entry was not a numeric value \n")
        print("The sum of your valid entries is: " + str(data))
        print("The number of valid entries was: " + str(count))
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that `float(string)` will never return `True`; it will always return a number of type `float` *or* it will raise a `ValueError` if the input cannot be converted to a float.

To fix this, you'll need to remove your `if` statement, and simply return `True` after calling `float(string)` in your `isfloat` function. If `float(string)` raises a `ValueError`, `isfloat` returns `False` as you would expect; otherwise, it will proceed and return `True`.

```
def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: `float(string) == True` will pass if `string` is `"1"` or `"1.0"`, because `True` is an `int` subclass with the value `1`. But it's a terrible test.

Comment: I agree, though I didn't mean to modify the rest of the code; I only intended to fix the issue the OP asked about. I'l modify my post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is ridiculous:

```
if float(string) == True:
```

That's checking if the `float` converted value is equal to `True` (which is numerically 1).

Just check for the exception and go:

```
def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `isfloat`. You shouldn't compare the result of `float` with `True`. Instead do something like:

```
def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

You don't need to actually *do* anything with the return value of `float`. If that call doesn't trigger an error -- you have a float, so just return `True`.

It might be tempting to use the line

```
if float(string): return True
```

That would *almost* work but would misclassify `"0"`

Comment: Thank you John. I'm only about a week in so the fog hasn't lifted just yet. That absolutely corrected the problem.